# SQL encoding problems (Â)

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

The website works and displayed correctly. 
But in the database, there is a lot of symbols like 'Â', â€‹ and so.
Any new entry in SQL is created with such symbols - but displayed properly on the Website.

The database is in UTF encoding.
The majority of the files too. But there are some files in ANSI (Windows-1252). I changed files that I found, it didn't help, there are hundreds of files...

By default, the browser shows website at UTF encoding. If I manually change to Windows-1252 in the browser, the characters starting to appear.

If I exporting SQL DB as UTF - characters are present in the damp.
If I exporting SQL DB as Windows-1252 the characters are not there.

Why the website display content properly, but in the DB there is some problem?
How to solve this?

Comment: See "Mojibake" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 
[`mysqli_set_charset('utf8');`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)

> Object oriented style
>
> bool mysqli::set_charset ( string $charset ) Procedural style
>
> bool mysqli_set_charset ( mysqli $link , string $charset )
>
> Sets the
>   default character set to be used when sending data from and to the
>   database server.

Comment: Thanks! It's always about that... To fix DB encoding I exported as Windows-1252 and uploaded as UTF, and then in the php connection: mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf8");

Comment: @VGranin, I'm glad this helped